# Sorceries in Combat phase

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I cast sorceries in combat phase, or only instants? For example, could I cast [Press into service](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPress%20into%20service%5d) after blockers are declared to take control of a declared blocker?

Comment: Although you may only cast sorceries on your turn during a main phase when the stack is empty, there are ways to circumvent that: [Quicken](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370644)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may only cast sorceries when it is your turn, during one of your main phases, while the stack is empty. So no you cannot cast them during combat.

> 307.1. A player who has priority may cast a sorcery card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty. Casting a sorcery as a spell uses the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Sorceries can't be cast during combat.

> 307.1. A player who has priority may cast a sorcery card from his or her hand during **a main phase** of his or her turn when the stack is empty. Casting a sorcery as a spell uses the stack. (See rule 601, “Casting Spells.”)